# Redirect old Wordpress posts to new pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Wordpress site and need to point specific posts from an old site to new posts this using htaccess. I want:

`http://domain.co.uk/?p=4449`

to redirect to:

`domain.co.uk/pagename`

This is what I'm using, which doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=4449$
RewriteRule ^(.*)?p=4449$ /pagename
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your site name/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your site name/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

OR

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem with a Wordpress plugin 'Redirect'.

I think there's some difficulty trying to rewrite index.php in Wordpress due to other rules in htaccess.